# Material SCSS overriding my SCSS in angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I am using material in my angular material and using mat-dialog.

Material default css class is overriding my custom css.

I can't use ngdeep as it is depreciated, view encapsulation or !important because neither of these considered good for production.

Also,i want to add SCSS to my angular component's SCSS file where i am adding mat-dialog and not in global styles file in angular.

Please help me out. Thank you

I tried adding panelClass but it is not working. I made it work with !important or adding SCSS in global styles file but i can't go with these options. I want to add SCSS to mat-dialog content through component's SCSS file